# Update state inside catch in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a script that sends requests to a 3rd party website, but after sometime the cookies are invalid & it throws a **403**

So I've got my script to send the request, if it throws the **403** then we send VALID cookies and then RESEND the request.

However it appears that the `state.device_info` remains undefined after updating it inside the catch function?

```js
(async () => {

    let state = {
        'access_denied': false,
        'cookies': {}
    };

    try {

        await getCookies(state);

        state.device_info = await getInfo(state).catch(async (error) => {
            let localError = handleError(error, state);
            if(localError === 'access_denied') {
                state.access_denied = true;
                //now lets unlock the request & send it again!
                let post = await sendValidCookies(state);
                if(post.data.success === true) {
                    //update state.device_info with WORKING request!
                    state.device_info = await getInfo(state).catch(async (error) => {
                        console.log('Damn we got another error!');
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                    if(state.device_info.status === 200) {
                        console.log('We got our info info using the unlocked request!');
                        state.access_denied = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(state.device_info === undefined || state.access_denied === true) {
            console.log('We have an undefined value!');
            console.log(state.device_info); //undefined
            console.log(state.access_denied); //false
            return false;
        }

    } catch(error) {
        console.log('major error!');
    }

})();
```

Comment: Try wrapping `await getInfo` with try/catch, instead of promise catch. I think your code below maybe executed before the error is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining it inside `catch`, just return the value. This returned value will be assigned to `state.device_info`

```
state.device_info = await getInfo(state).catch(async (error) => {
    let localError = handleError(error, state);
        if(localError === 'access_denied') {
            state.access_denied = true;
            //now lets unlock the request & send it again!
            let post = await sendValidCookies(state);
            if(post.data.success === true) {
                //Get result from WORKING request
                const result = await getInfo(state).catch(async (error) => {
                    console.log('Damn we got another error!');
                    console.log(error);
                });

                if(state.device_info.status === 200) {
                    console.log('We got our info info using the unlocked request!');
                    state.access_denied = false;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `await` keyword in front of your method call `getInfo(state)` and you're calling `.catch(...)` right after, I assume `getInfo(state)` returns a Promise.

There are two ways you can handle Promise in JavaScript:

- By explicitly call `.then(result => {...})` while catching errors with `.catch(error => {...})`.
- By putting the `await` keyword in front of your method call. By using this syntax, and if you want to catch errors (which you should do), you need to use the `try { } catch (error) { }` syntax.

I've never mix those two methods like you did and I think this might be the origin of the issue you're experiencing.

For your case, it should look like this:

```
try {
  state.device_info = await getInfo(state);
} catch (error) {
  // Your logic here...
}
```